# How to iterate through a list of an anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, anonymous-types

I have a list of Countries and i would like to separately get the name of the country and the CountryID.

To be more understandable please visit this link where i have uploaded an image

[alt text http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/8505/listx.jpg](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/8505/listx.jpg)

http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/8505/listx.jpg

How is this possible with an anonymous type?

I tried Countries[0]["Country"]  but with no luck.

Answer (score 24):

Just loop over your list - the anonymous type is anonymous - but still a strict type! You can get intellisense and should be able to access the fields `Country` and `CountryID` with no problem at all:

```
foreach(var c in yourListOfCountries)
{
   string countryName = c.Country;
   int countryID = c.CountryID;
}
```

Marc

Comment: I thought that anonymous types handled from a different way.
As I saw I could also use LINQ.
Thanks marc_s.

Comment: No, there's nothing special about anonymous types - other than the fact *you* as a developer don't know their type name. But there **is** a full type definition behind them and you can use them just as absolutely normal types.

Comment: if you want to remove several items from this list you will get an exception in a foreach loop - the only way to remove them is to iterate from backwards and this is only possible by using a for loop. therefor you will need an index [i]. so we are back at the beginnig. is it possible to iterate by index? ;)